# Cloud based memoizing

Tags: python, cloud, decorator, memoization, python-decorators

I use python decorators to memoize certain methods, but the cache is lost when the program terminates. I have thought about implementing cloud based memoizing where the cache is stored in MongoDB, but I am wondering if there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [joblib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib). It has a memoize-to-disk decorator that does this locally. Making it cache results elsewhere could be doable too by inheritance, but not something I've actually seen. You could easily write one yourself by looking at the lru_cache implementation in functools or its backport clones and changing how it interacts with the cache object, so it talks with a database rather than a dictionary.

Just remember that there's a price to be paid for querying a database that makes it harder to benefit from a cache except on very long running tasks.

Alternatively, you can write a simple atexit handle to go through each functools.lru_cache instance and dump their caches to json or pickles and re-load them as part of the init process.